# compilation problem in rosjava (master branch)

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Source%20Installation and I'm getting these compilation errors: http://pastebin.com/LV31s8g0 after issuing catkin_make
can anyone help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140371/compilation-problem-in-rosjava-(master-branch)/) by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a recent commit in master for this that is probably causing the problems. You might like to follow this up there: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/pull/19/.

Master is also pretty volatile. Been hard to manage/maintain it so that the various build workflows stay working. Unless you're experimenting with the rosjava code (and know well what you're doing), hydro is a better choice to base your own development on.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on 2014-03-16**:
Thanks Daniel. the only reason that I've tried to work with the master build, is that when I've used the hydro build, and then went on to compile android_apps (after it compiles with catkin_make) - I've tried to import the project into android studio, and started getting errors

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-03-16**:
If you have errors with the hydro build, post some issues on github. I can remedy them much faster in hydro than master. Recently there was an android studio upgrade - that may have been your source of errors. I'll be going through the pull requests up on github now to fix them early this week.